# How to create a PDF file from my page in the React based project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jspdf, html2canvas

I tried make this PDF file with **html2canvas** and **jspdf**:

```
const input = document.getElementById('pdfTest')!;
html2canvas(input)
      .then((canvas) => {
           const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
           const pdf = new jsPDF();
          * pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);
           pdf.save("download.pdf");
      });
```

But in the * line I got this error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Supplied Data is not a valid base64-String jsPDF.convertStringToImageData
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use following method (you can change font size/style):

```
printDet = (e) => {
        html2canvas(document.querySelector("#pdfTest")).then(canvas => {

            const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            const pdf = new jsPDF();

            pdf.setFontSize(20)
            pdf.setFontStyle("bold")
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 210, 200, 'alias');

            pdf.save('download.pdf');

        });

    }
```

Don't forget to import:

`import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';`

`import jsPDF from 'jspdf';`